# Correct way to build FormData object to POST file in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, forms, multipartform-data, multer

I'd like to post an image file selected by the user to a nodejs express backend. Therefore I have a file input `<input type="file">` and want to put the file into a multipart formdata object.

I do it like in the following. `console.log()` outputs are below.

```
 upload(dataToBeUploaded: { data: File }) {
    const serveruploadurl = `http://${this.config.serverHost}:${this.config.serverPort}/${this.config.imageRoute}/${this.config.uploadRoute}`;
    let formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('image', dataToBeUploaded.data, dataToBeUploaded.data.name);
    console.log('File image: ', dataToBeUploaded.data);
    console.log('This is created formdata')
    console.log(formdata);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(serveruploadurl, formdata, httpOptions || {})
        .subscribe(
          response => resolve(response),
          err => reject(err)
        );
    });
 }
```

```
// console.log() outputs on selection of .png image
File image:  
File { name: "D9AE7757-33D9-4544-9A03-FC447BDFC1D1.png", lastModified: 1571310436000, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 435504, type: "image/png" }

This is created formdata
FormData {  
<prototype>: FormDataPrototype
​}

Received server upload error response:  
Object { headers: {…}, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", url: "http://localhost:3000/image/upload", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/image/upload: 500 Internal Server Error", error: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Error: Multipart: Boundary not found<br>
```

So the file is there but the formdata does not get populated with the file. It only contains a prototype. What am I doing wrong in creating the form data object?

Thanks!

**Note 1:** on the server I use `multer` to parse the form data, but in this case I get the error

> Error: Multipart: Boundary not found

**Note 2:** Angular version from package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/http": "^7.1.3",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
```

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' })
};
```

Comment: What does `httpOptions` say? What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: @Quentin I think I use very recent ones.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin! This solved the issue.